# Match a URL that is not in a set of URL types?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to replace URLs that are NOT images or YouTube videos with the following:

```
preg_replace('#(http://([^\s]*)(?<!\.(?:jpg|gif|png))(?<!youtube\.com/watch\?v=\w{11}))#', '<a href = $1> $1 </a>', $output);
```

This still matches URLs like **http://foobar.com/baz.jp**g and **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghij**k, where the bolded parts show what is matched.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `[\s]*` which lazily matches non-spacy characters. It will however trackback if the following assertion isn't matched. So you have to make it possessive.

Use `\S*+` to do so. Where `\S` means all non-space characters (same as `[^\s]` really, but terser). And the `+` after the `*` quantifier avoids that PCRE retracts character-wise in case of assertion failures.

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Also you should preferrably move the video assertion after that `http://` part with `(?!youtube)` rather than matching it from behind. There might be other URL parameters in Youtube links, so just match until `/watch`